# How to bind object on DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

In my DataGrid if I have the following binding I get the User_ID no problem. Each row is a User record. How do I change this to bind the actual User Object? So I can send it into my converter.

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.User_ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `.User_ID` from binding path :

```
{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
```

Comment: Afraid this did not work. I test it in the converter by doing:  Users.User u = values[0] as Users.User;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (u == null)); and it outputs true.

Comment: what is column `type` content if you put `values[0]` in Visual Studio's watch window? in other words, of what type is `values[0]` you got actually? because null can happen if `values[0]` is actually null, or if conversion to type `Users.User` failed.

Comment: Ah you were right on the money, binding was working, however I was casting it into User when it should have been UserViewModel. Just as a note, I also tried Chris' suggestion however it did not work without the path.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'path' from the binding as follows:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}
```

Comment: Afraid this did not work. I test it in the converter by doing:  Users.User u = values[0] as Users.User;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (u == null)); and it outputs true.